# What mechanism makes outer variables accessible within objects created out of a class on the fly

Tags: java

I have the following piece of code:

```
private void renderText(ArrayList<ArticleWord> words) {
        final StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Log.d("findWordForRightHanded", text.toString());
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I don't understand how the variable `text` created inside `renderText` method is accessible within `onTouch` method of `View.OnTouchListener` class?

And how is this mechanism called in Java when a class is defined and at the same time a new object is created from that class?

Comment: The `text` variable is assigned to a `text` field in your anonymous class for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called [variable capturing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html), and on a basic level it copies the value of the variable at the object's creation to a synthetic field. (That is, a field that is auto-generated by the compiler.) So your compiled code will look a bit like this:

```
    final StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    tv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(text) {
        private final StringBuilder text;

        private View.OnTouchListener(StringBuilder text) { // THIS IS NOT VALID SYNTAX, JUST DEMONSTRATING WHAT'S GOING ON BEHIND THE SCENES
           this.text = text;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d("findWordForRightHanded", text.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is why the variable needs to be final or effectively final (this latter concept came in with Java 8, and it means that if the compiler can ascertain that you don't assign the variable more than once, you don't have to explicitly declare it as final), so that the value is still considered valid when the overridden method is eventually called.

It's important to note at this point that one thing that is always captured in a non-static inner class is a reference to `OuterClass.this`, which is why you can end up with strange memory leaks if you aren't careful enough. Non-static inner class have no such problems, and lambdas offer a more robust solution too.

**Update:** Sorry, you asked for the name of the whole mechanism, that is called an `anonymous class`.

Comment: I don't believe lambdas are available on Android yet, although Groovy is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on effectively final thing in Java 8.

Comment: @chrylis I don't know about Android variations, but lambdas came in with Java 8.

Comment: Right, and I believe Android is still on 7.

Comment: @chrylis Well, that explains it then :)

Answer (score 4):

The `OnTouchListener` is an inner class, and instances of inner classes have an implicit reference to their containing outer objects.

In this case, it also happens to be an *anonymous class*, which is a convenience syntax often used in cases like these. It'll be compiled into its own `.class` file with a name like `OuterClass$1`.

Comment: thanks, _instances of inner classes have an implicit reference to their containing outer objects_ - up to the containing class level fields or only to the containing method fields?

Comment: can you please comment on my previous comment?

Comment: @Maximus Only to fields; all block-level variables are on the stack. As biziclop explained, the compiler does some sleight of hand to convert block-level captured variables to synthetic fields.

Comment: thanks, so instances of inner classes have an implicit reference to class level fields (this is _not_ variable capturing), but with the help of compiler block level (local) variables are _also_ accessible to inner class instances and these block level variables are _captured_, correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is **variable capturing**.

When an anonymous inner class is created inside any method, all the `final` variables defined within the method are accessible in the inner class.

For **Scalar** type, after it has been assigned value, it can't be changed. For **Object** type, after it has been assigned a reference, it can't be changed.

Java compiler **Captures** the value/reference of final variables at runtime and preserves a copy for inner class. Once the scope of the outer method ends the value/reference of final variables vanishes but the captured copy for inner class exists in the class memory.

Comment: What about the accessibility of "Effective Final" local variables inside an anonymous inner class? Does it compiler behaves the same as that of what it does with Final variable?

Comment: @LalitRao, an anonymous inner class can access local variables and parameters of enclosing block that are final or effectively final (since Java 8). And yes the compiler behaves same with the effectively final variables as it does with final variables.